# Will uninstalling a game on my PS4 remove it forever?

Tags: ps4, psn

On my PlayStation 4, I bought the Evil Within (digital only). If I uninstalled the game to save disc space, will I not be able to install it for free in the future and have to rebuy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bound to your account. So you can download and install the game in the future again (for free) whenever you want and have the diskspace. Furthermore, you can even continue with your previous save game! [Source](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/playstation-nation-1000002/ps4-500gb-hard-drive-almost-full-with-just-game-in-31698016/)

Comment: The only time this wouldn't be valid is if for some reason it is removed from the Marketplace, though this is rare.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Ah, that is a good exception you're pointing out there. Do you know by any chance if this is happening much?

Comment: He said it's rare :P

Comment: @djsmiley2k Knowing Konami and P.T. (luckily I got it in time), it might occur more often.

Comment: @Mathias711 only heard of it twice, but can't recall which games -- one game was completely broken, the other.... I can't recall why.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Okay. It was just an indication for me if this happens a lot or not. So not so much, luckily.

Comment: @Mathias711 http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_delisted_PSN_games